# Converting rows to columns and columns to rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my existing table:

```
id  |user-LastName  |user-FirstName |manager-lasename   |manager-firstname
22   Gould              Todd             raj                 kumar
23   Volk               Michael          anil                tej
24   Sarosiek           Kristi           mahesh              banda
```

I need to get the following result:

```
id  name                user          manager      
22  last name           gould          raj     
22  first name          todd           kumar       
23  last name           Volk           anil    
23  first name          Michael        tej     
24  last name           Sarosiek       mahesh      
24  first name          Kristi         banda
```

I've tried using `PIVOT`, but I can't get it to work.  Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Your table seems to have some potential normalization issues. Shouldn't you have the manager's information in another table? Not sure what the table is but it is likely that the user data should also be in a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the design here which I think is the crux of your problem you can get the data pretty easily with a UNION.

```
select id
    , 'LastName' as name
    , userLastName
    , ManagerLastName
from SomeTable

union all

select id
    , 'FirstName' as name
    , userFirstName
    , ManagerfirstName
from SomeTable

order by id
    , name desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you aren't really trying to Pivot here, but just orient your existing data in a different way.

One approach to getting your desired results would be to create two queries and union:

```
select id, 'FirstName' as name, user_firstName as "user" , manager_firstname as manager from p
union
select id, 'LastName' as name, user_LastName as "user" , manager_lastname as manager from p;
```

[Here is a functional example](http://rextester.com/YZS50343)